# Hide Activity in the Background

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have two Theme.AppCompat.Dialog-Activitys. If i open the second Activity, I can still see the first Activity in the Background.

I tried:

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
```

and

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
```

Both solve my prolem in principal, but if i press the back button, it does not show my first Activity. 
Is there an Flag that solves my problem without ruining the hierarchical order?

Answer (score 0):

So what I can understood from the question is, you want to close the MyDialog-Activity as soon as the "AnotherActivity" is launched from MyDialog-Activity. So that tapping back button from newly launched "AnotherActivity" lead to the "firstActivity" (the parent activity of the MyDialog-Activity) instead of the MyDialog-Activity, Right?

If I understood it correctly then you can try by calling `finish();` after `startActivity(intent);`

So it should look something like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AnotherActivity.class);
MyDialogActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
MyDialogActivity.this.finish();
```

Comment: Hi, im sorry for the missunderstanding.
I have two Activitys, A and B.
If i start B from A, i can see A still in the Background (doesnt look nice).
I want to hide it, but if i press Back, i want to return to A. (like default)